# Django, passing data through a view context, preferred storage method

Tags: python, django, list, class

I'm trying to pass some data through a django context and am finding it kind of cumbersome. I'm very new to Python and a bit unfamiliar with storing data, I have a few suggestions here shown in the code:
1. A form to pass data:

```
def formview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=LogonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['firstname']=form.cleaned_data['entrykey']
            request.session['lastname']=form.cleaned_data['firstfield']
            request.session['age']=form.cleaned_data['secondfield']
            request.session['location']=form.cleaned_data['thirdfield']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
    else:
        form=LogonForm()

    return render(request, 'logon/form.html', {'form': form})
```

A view which reacts to the submitted data, but not from database:

```
def thanksforform(request):
    try:
        #Using class
        class thanksclass():
            firstname=request.session['firstname']
            lastname=request.session['lastname']
            age=request.session['age']
            location=request.session['location']
            under18='Come back in %s years' % str(18-age)
            over18='Step right up!'
        #Using array
        data=np.empty(6, dtype=object)
        data[0]=request.session['firstname'] #etc. etc. ect.
        #using list
        listdata=[request.session['firstname']] #etc etc etc
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/logon/')
    request.session.flush()
    return render(request, 'logon/thanks.html', {'thanksclass': thanksclass})
```

Which type of object is preferred in Django for this kind of purpose, is there a better way to pass data through the view context?

PS. Please disregard the source being session data, It's just an example as I was messing around, I'm aware that you can call session data directly from the template aswell.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, depends on how I'm retrieving/creating the data.

In general forms are a nice way to do it if you want to have some validation or allow the user to submit data or if you're representing something from the ORM but Django's templates accept a lot of data types.

Otherwise I'd recommend creating a dictionary and setting content equal to it. I.E.

```
varOne = '1'
varTwo = 'Two'
varThree = 3.0
myPassThrougData = 
  {'variableOne': varOne, 'variableTwo': varTwo, 'VariableThree': 
  varThree }
return render(request, 'logon/form.html', {'form': form}, content=myPassThoughData)
```